# PhraseMatcher SpaCy Attribute Error: 'spacy.matcher.phrasematcher.PhraseMatcher' object attribute 'add' is read-only

Tags: python

*Hi Everyone*

Im sifting through texts using Spacy PhraseMatcher for multiple labels.

`e.g Steve Jobs is the CEO of Apple.`

So Im trying to get this output 
`Steve Jobs (PERSON), CEO (POSITION) and Apple (ENTITY)`

I got this error - anyone came across this before?

AttributeError: 'spacy.matcher.phrasematcher.PhraseMatcher' object attribute 'add' is read-only

Thanks...

Comment: Can you share a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Hi @GonzaloHernandez I have edited the code above

Comment: Hi, it's probably better if you add some example text instead of loading a JSON file. As it stands, this is not a minimal reproducible example. Also, could you add the line on which it throws the error?

Comment: hi @amdex, I tried subsitituting JSON with plain text instead. The error still stands:
```AttributeError: 'spacy.matcher.phrasematcher.PhraseMatcher' object attribute 'add' is read-onl
y```

Answer (score 0):

`PhraseMatcher.add` [is a method](https://spacy.io/api/phrasematcher#add)

```
matcher.add('POSITION', None, *position)
matcher.add('LOCATION', None, *location)
matcher.add('PERSON', None ,*person)
```

---

Working example with other errors fixed

```
import spacy
from spacy.matcher import PhraseMatcher
from spacy.lang.en import English
import json

nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
matcher = PhraseMatcher(nlp.vocab, attr = "LOWER")

TEXTS = "Steve Jobs is the CEO of Apple"
nlp = English(nlp.vocab)
position = [nlp(text) for text in ('CEO','CFO','COO')]
company =[nlp(text) for text in ('APPLE','GOOGLE','TWITTER')]
person = [nlp(text) for text in ('STEVE JOBS', 'LARRY PAGE', 'JACK SPARROW')]

matcher.add('POSITION', None, *position)
matcher.add('LOCATION', None, *company)
matcher.add('PERSON', None ,*person)

doc = nlp(TEXTS)
matches = matcher(doc)
for match_id, start, end in matches:
    rule_id = nlp.vocab.strings[match_id]
    span = doc [start:end] #matched span
    print (match_id,rule_id, start,end, span.text)
```

Comment: The error states ```AttributeError: 'spacy.matcher.phrasematcher.PhraseMatcher' object attribute 'add' is read-onl
y```... so Im not sure what this means. Thanks for the help

Comment: it means that if you do `print(PhraseMatcher.add)` you get `<method 'add' of 'spacy.matcher.phrasematcher.PhraseMatcher' objects>` which means that `.add` should be treated as a function. The linked documentation in my answer explains the parameters of this function

Comment: Thank you !! I'll try yours with JSON file.

Comment: somehow JSON doesnt work though I imported the necessary library. with text works perfect.

Comment: what are the contents of the JSON?

Comment: [
  "Larry Page is the COO of Google",
  "Steve Jobs, the CEO of Apple, resides in New York.",
  "Is Jack Sparrow the CFO of Twitter?",
  
]

Comment: you either have to loop over TEXTS and feed each str to `nlp()` in every iteration or you could join everything into a single text with `TEXTS = " ".join(TEXTS)`